# MediaRecorder in Android 8.0 oreo

Tags: android

Hey I'm recording the sound in the background , everything is fine but in Android 8.0 oreo Record only half an hour Then kills the MediaRecorder.
I tried to track the error but did not succeed , By OnTaskRemoved or OnDestroy (Service)
Are there solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Android O kills every background service to preserve battery. To keep your service alive longer it needs to be in foreground (with a visible notification).

Comment: Okay then how does the WhatsApp work, running all the time (without a visible notification)

Comment: @NidalWahhoud I don't use WhatsApp - what feature do you mean?

Comment: I mean , It receives messages, video and audio, whenever it comes , there is something working on in the background and the Android do not kill something